# Why is inequality reversed when prooving Chebyshev's inequality?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

http://math.wikia.com/wiki/Proof_of_Chebyshev%27s_inequality

There you can find the proof of mentioned inequality. Could someone explain me why does the inequality get reversed when squaring both sides?

I find following explanation insufficient: *Notice that the direction of the inequality changes since squaring causes the right-hand expression to become positive.*

Comment: Because $-k\sigma$ is negative. For example $-4<-3$ implies $(-4)^2>(-3)^2$.

Comment: So simple but still didn't figure it out... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\sigma$, the standard deviation is always positive. Therefore, the $k\sigma$ in $x-\mu < -k\sigma$ is always negative. I will show why squaring both sides does not work in this case:

A clear example would be to use $-2 < 1$. Squaring both sides without changing the sign gives $4 < 1$, which is obviously false.

More generally, when we have $a^2 > b^2$, since $(x^2)^{1/2}$ can be either $+x$ or $-x$, when we take the square root of both sides we have $4$ cases: $a > b$; $-a > b$; $a > -b$; and $-a > -b$. We can observe that **all of the cases** are not necessarily true.

Answer (score 0):

Both sides of the inequality (before squaring) are negative. If $a$ and $b$ are positive, then $-a < -b \Rightarrow a > b \Rightarrow a^2 > b^2$.